# Computer shuts down instead of going to sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power, shutdown, desktop-computer

I have a windows 10 computer, and whenever I press the power button, even though it is set to sleep, shuts down the computer anyway. It does this when I select sleep from the start menu as well.
In power settings, I have "turn off hard disk after" to 0, I have "fast boot" off, I've made sure that the power button is set to sleep(but it doesn't matter since it does it from the start menu as well).

When I make it go to sleep, the display goes black, but the backlight is still on, the power indicator and hard drive indicator on my pc is also on for about a minute until all 3 turn off, and the computer shuts down.

I can't find anything online about this, and I'm not sure what to do, thank you in advance

Comment: Are you just pressing the power button or holding it down?

Comment: @Aardwolf yeah, I'm just pressing the button, it also does this if I select sleep from the start menu, so I don't think the power button is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my BIOS and it went to sleep properly